# Combining two similar columns from 2 different tables with no relationship

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Hi my project works on Django Python. What I want to achieve is since django tasty pie doesn't support combining two resources(no relationship b/w the tables), I need to come up with my own resource. Here I have 2 tables, Table A and B. There is no relationship b/w these 2 tables. But both the tables have a field/column named `gname` in common. So I want to get all the distinct gnames from both the tables and put it into one list (no duplicated values) and I need to display these gnames as a list in my template. Is there anyway to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of [deleting your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33383762/1324033), *respond* to the comments and update it with new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
gnames1 = list(A.objects.values_list('gname',flat=True).distinct())
gnames2 = list(B.objects.values_list('gname',flat=True).distinct())

gnames = list(set(gnames1+gnames2))
render(request, 'sampletemplate.html', {'gnames':gnames})
```

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is a data structure that doesn't allow duplicate values.

You can add all the values from both the tables to it and I think you are good to go.

[Python Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)